# mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. even i added MatFormFieldModule

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-6

Here im new to Angular Material please help me why im getting Error. I was copied code from https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select">
      <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

This is the same code which i copied from that url
**App.module.ts**

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
  imports: [
MatFormFieldModule,MatInputModule]
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you forgot about `MatSelectModule`:

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
...
imports: [MatFormFieldModule,MatInputModule,MatSelectModule]
```

Comment: I added mat button and this issue appeared again.
    <button mat-button  >Login</button>

Answer (score 2):

Try Removing placeholder="Input" of input box.
It worked for me give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps, here is my `app.module.ts` for my app using material:

```
import {
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
} from '@angular/material';

....

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    .....,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    .....,
  ],
    .....
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

import {MatInputModule} from  '@angular/material';

@NgModule({

imports: [

```
MatInputModule
```

],
  exports:[
     MatInputModule

]
})

at app.module.ts  file

Answer (score 0):

Remove placeholder from input tag.

Instead of using placeholder you could use

`<mat-label>.....</mat-label>`

Here is code:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
       <input matInput required />
       <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
 </mat-form-field>
```